# Correct way to execute a function when I have function name

Tags: javascript

I have a string `"Car.run(true)"` or `"Car.find('window')"`, I want to execute the function `run` or `find` and also pass respective parameters passed. What is the correct way to do it without using `eval`?

I tried to split the string, extracted the function name and parameters using regex but issue is with boolean values(it will a string after extraction).

Can anyone guide me to resolve this blocker?

Comment: You can cast to a boolean `const bool = myBooleanString === "true"`.

Comment: Please provide code sample?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript land, classes are just objects that can be referenced using dictionary lookup syntax

```
class Car { run(x) { return x } find(x) { return x }  }
car = new Car()
method_name = 'run'
car[method_name]    # == ƒ run(x) { return x }
car[method_name](1) # == 1
```

In python land you would need `hasattr()` and `getattr()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply like below, if you dont want to use `eval`:

```
var functionHolder = "Car.run(true)";
var myTmpFunction = new Function(functionHolder);
myTmpFunction ();  //This would invoke
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally using `eval` is not a good idea, and this isn't great either but it's a start:

```js
function Car() {
  this.run = function(args) {
    console.log('Running', args)
  }
}

const str = "Car.run(true)";

// Get the constructor name and the function with arguments as a string
const [ctor, fn] = str.split('.');

// The name of the function without parens
const fnName = fn.replace(/\((.+)\)/, '')

// Get the argument list of the function
const originalArgs = fn.match(/\((.+)\)/)

// Clean arguments
const args = originalArgs[1]
  .split(',')
  .map(str => str.trim())
  .filter(Boolean);

// Instantiate a new object based on the name
const f = new(Function.prototype.bind.apply(window[ctor]))();

// Invoke the function with the arguments
f[fnName].apply(f, args) // Running  true
```

General idea comes from the [AngularJS source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/26a5779cddf70944b7548e3a6410d35237a516e5/src/auto/injector.js#L952) and how it instantiates objects from strings.